# Loop folder created on desktop automatically

Tags: windows, loops, directory, windows-10, desktop

Anyone knows what is the folder with ###loop name on desktop, it appears and also it is deletable.
but any knows what is this?

Best Regards,
Sara

Answer (score 0):

Actually this not any issue , i think while you try to run any batch script or package that have created ###loop folder like this name.
Thanks,
Udhaya Kumar